# Vuejs passing arguments with a routes href link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm quite new to Vuejs, so Sorry in advance!
I have a component called "Goods" which shows all the items in a route path ("/Goods") and another component called "AddGoods" at ("/AddGoods") which is a form and submits data to my database table.
I have to use two separate pages for these two and they work closely together.
now I also want to be able to use my AddGoods form for editing and showing details on my already added Goods and I'm having trouble finding a way to send some parameter with the link so that I could manage my field and buttons based on each situation (like making fields readonly for showing details and so on).

here's my route.js :

```
{
    path: "/addGoods",
    name: "add goods",
    meta: {
      title: "Add Goods",
    },
    component: () => import("../views/GoodsManagment/AddGoods.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/goodsTbl",
    name: "goods tbl",

    meta: {
      title: "Goods Table",
    },
    component: () => import("../views/GoodsManagment/GoodsTbl.vue"),
  },
```

and here's the link to "AddGoods" :

```
 <v-btn v-on="click" href="/AddGoods"> Add a new item </v-btn>
```

Comment: Have a look at [Passing Props to Route Components](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode) and see if this solves your problem.

Comment: thanks but I've already checked that and I couldn't figure out exactly what was it that they were trying to explain and i don't think it fixes my problem.

Comment: You should define the props that you need on your component and then when you set `{path: "xxx", component: "yyy", props: true}` your component will be able to react on routes like `/AddGoods?good=pencil&amount=3&price=4.35&details=true`

Comment: I added the following : props: true in routes.js file , inserting= "false" in data() , href='/AddGoods?inserting="true"' in the button , v-if="inserting" in an element so i could see the results! when I click on the button i go to the link (/AddGoods?inserting="true") but the element is still hidden which means that the inserting is still false.

Comment: I also tried `this.$router.push({ name: "add goods", params: { inserting: true } });` to call the page and added `this.inserting = this.$router.params.inserting;` to use it on the other page but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up doing it like this :

route.js:

```
{
    path: "/addGoods/:id",
    name: "add goods",
    meta: {
      title: "Add Goods",
    },
    component: () => import("../views/GoodsManagment/AddGoods.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/goodsTbl",
    name: "goods tbl",

    meta: {
      title: "Goods Table",
    },
    component: () => import("../views/GoodsManagment/GoodsTbl.vue"),
  },
```

and to call it , I personally found the Programmatic Navigation easier to use, so :

```
this.$router.push({name: "add goods", params: { id: 123 }});
```